# How to change language of dictation without changing keyboard input source?

Tags: macos, keyboard, voice-dictation

I'm working with an English external keyboard with a Mac (currently running Sonoma) hat also has a built-in German keyboard which I only use occasionally. I use dictation in both English and German. Now, my problem is that when I switch dictation from English to German, my Mac seems to think the keys jump around on my keyboard :-) and switches the input source to German, too. In fact, I have not found a way to have German dictation without having to switch the keyboard back to English when I want to type something again, which is pretty annoying.

So, is there a way to switch dictation to German while keeping the keyboard input in English, or is there another workaround for this bug? Thanks so much!

Update: I am switching dictation language not in the settings, but in the popup that appears when using the dictation shortcut. (see screenshot below). In case that matters: I have German, English "US international - PC" and "Britsh - PC" input sources installed, for the different keyboards.

[image: popup]

Comment: @TomGewecke Right - the dictation popup switches both input source and dictation. :-(

Comment: I only have Ventura where the popup for mike language is independent of the keyboard one.  Does anything happen if you click only on the microphone?  There are ways to get rid of the new keyboard popup, I wonder if that would help.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thank you for checking! Well, perhaps they broke that with Sonoma. When I switch the input source in the menu bar, that switches the dictation language, too, and vice versa - I haven't found a way to separate that so far. :-(

Comment: The info on changing the new language popup is at https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007827 but I don't know if it will help your issue

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks! That did nothing when I tried it and if would have switched off the language popup that wouldn't help me, because I need switching it rather often. It's just that I only need to switch the dictation language, not the keyboard layout. 8-}